# How Can I Get an Icon or thumbnail for a Specific file

Tags: python, linux, shell

I am searching for a way to get the icon associated with a certain file type on Linux.

Either using a shell script or python.

I prefer a native python method which works on all the platforms, but a shell script method would be ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution, and I wrote a function to do the job

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gio, gtk, os

def get_icon_filename(filename,size):
    #final_filename = "default_icon.png"
    final_filename = ""
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        # Get the icon name
        file = gio.File(filename)
        file_info = file.query_info('standard::icon')
        file_icon = file_info.get_icon().get_names()[0]
        # Get the icon file path
        icon_theme = gtk.icon_theme_get_default()
        icon_filename = icon_theme.lookup_icon(file_icon, size, 0)
        if icon_filename != None:
            final_filename = icon_filename.get_filename()
    return final_filename
            
        
print (get_icon_filename("/home/el7r/Music/test.mp3",64))
```

thanks all

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [@Ali_AlNoaimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441897/ali-alnoaimi) for his solution . I changed it to work with python3 and PyGI :

```
import os , gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gio , Gtk


def get_thumbnail(filename,size):
    final_filename = ""
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        file = Gio.File.new_for_path(filename)
        info = file.query_info('standard::icon' , 0 , Gio.Cancellable())
        icon = info.get_icon().get_names()[0]

        icon_theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()
        icon_file = icon_theme.lookup_icon(icon , size , 0)
        if icon_file != None:
            final_filename = icon_file.get_filename()
        return final_filename

print(get_thumbnail("/path/to/file",32))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that icon files are the same across platforms...

On a Mac, the icons are stored in the application bundle - EG:

```
/Applications/Mail.app/Contents/Resources/app.icns
```

In Linux they seem to be in a similar, but different place EG:

```
 /usr/lib/firefox/icons/mozicon16.xpm
```

So, I think you are out of luck for an easy, cross-platform solution and will have to code the routine to look into the appropriate place for each OS

Answer (score -2):

ImageMagick is pretty good for basic manipulation from the command line. Info at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Comment: It seems that this package only makes thumbnails for images, and edits images, could it generate a thumbnail , or icon for mpg,ogg,mp3,zip,tar.gz ?