# Get the default icon for specific file type in Ubuntu OS by python

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk

In my ubuntu PC, and by python script, I need to get the default path of icon of specific file type.

as :

```
def get_icon_path(extenstion):
    ...
    ...
    return icon_path
```

> get_icon_path("py")
>
> /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/text-x-python.svg

N.B: I read this question, which act only with currently existing files.

[How Can I Get an Icon or thumbnail for a Specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203251/how-can-i-get-an-icon-or-thumbnail-for-a-specific-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GNU/Linux desktop environments do not assign icons to filename suffixes (extensions). Rather, they assign icons to Internet media types (MIME types), and a file’s type may or may not be determined by its filename suffix (content sniffing may also be involved). You can use the [`mimetypes`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/mimetypes.html) module from the standard library to guess the media type from the suffix. Then [`gio.content_type_get_icon`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/gio-functions.html#function-gio--content-type-get-icon), and from then on it’s as in the question you linked.

```
import mimetypes

import gio
import gtk

def get_icon_path(extension, size=32):
    type_, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type('x.' + extension)
    if type_:
        icon = gio.content_type_get_icon(type_)
        theme = gtk.icon_theme_get_default()
        info = theme.choose_icon(icon.get_names(), size, 0)
        if info:
            return info.get_filename()
```

Comment: if info:return info.get_filename(). Is it possible to return None despite the file type is known to the system.

Comment: @esnadr Don’t know, just being defensive there.

Comment: How would you do the same thing in GTK3?

Comment: @xuhdev If my code doesn’t port straightforwardly to GTK+3, I think it’s better to ask a separate question.

Comment: I've posted another answer for GTK3.

Answer (score 2):

For GTK3, use

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio

def get_icon_path(mimetype, size=32):
    icon = Gio.content_type_get_icon(mimetype)
    theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()
    info = theme.choose_icon(icon.get_names(), size, 0)
    if info:
        print(info.get_filename())
```