# How to get the icon of the associated app of a given file on macOS programmatically?

Tags: python, macos, shell

How to get the icon of the associated app of a given file on macOS programmatically? I would like to show the icons that are used by Finder for each file. Either shell or Python scripts should be fine.

This is the macOS version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203251/how-can-i-get-an-icon-or-thumbnail-for-a-specific-file)

Comment: Hi, what have you tried? What have you searched? is there a specific error you are running into in your own code?

Comment: @nephi12 I don't know where to start.

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted. This is a proper programming question, and I couldn't find any useful information on the Internet.

Comment: You might try `geticon` from OSX Utils. http://osxutils.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/osxutils/osxutils/src/geticon.m?view=markup

Comment: An example is available [here](https://gitlab.com/xuhdev/dired-icon/blob/master/get-icon-path-macos.m)